# Whats wrong in this Routing code - Angular 8

Tags: angular2-routing, angular8

I am providing the link to my GitHub codebase. Its simple Routing code but not even Home component displaying. I am not able to find whats went wrong in this. Please help me. Please go through connection in app-routing.module.ts as well as app.component.html

https://github.com/sireeshap/besty/blob/master/src/app/app.component.html

app.component.html

```
<header>
<div class='container'>
<a href='#' routerLink='/' class='logo'>Ethics & Habits</a>
 <nav>
   <ul>
  <li><a herf='#' routerLink='/' routerLinkActive="active">Home</a> .</li>
  <li><a  routerLink='/about' routerLinkActive="active">About</a></li>
  <li><a herf='#' routerLink='/vision' routerLinkActive="active">Vision</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</div>
</header>

  <div class='container'>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppHomeComponent } from './app-home/app-home.component';
import { AppVisionComponent } from './app-vision/app- vision.component';
import {AppAboutComponent} from './app-about/app-about.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path : ' ',  redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {path : 'home', component : AppHomeComponent},
  {path : 'about ',  component : AppAboutComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path : 'vision',  component : AppVisionComponent}
 ];

@NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
    })
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for asking the blunt question. Extra space added before path in app-routing.module.ts